# What is the significance of hosts file and is it used as a loophole/bypass restrictions?

Tags: windows, sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, hosts-file

I came across one question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35269421/1223045) which instructs the user to fiddle with the hosts file in order to bypass a "update check".

The software in question is Sublime Text Editor and the OP is asking for a way to disable update checks. The solution is to add a line in the hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 www.sublimetext.com
```

Now whether that's acceptable or not is a different question. What I'm interested to know is what exactly happens if I put that in the hosts file and how does it solve the OP's problem?

Answer (score 2):

All a hosts file does is map domain names to IP addresses.  When they are mapped to 127.0.0.1 they are being mapped to your local machine.

In this case when the software looks for updates it is checking against a known domain name.  By redirecting that domain name to the local machine instead of the correct machine, the check will fail, and the update cant occur.  NOTE THAT BROWSING TO THE WEBSITE www.sublimetext.com will also fail.

There is nothing inherently questionable about using a hosts file on your own equipment, and indeed every major OS uses them.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question about how the internet works.

When you type in an address in a browser such as Google.com, your computer needs to know the actual IP address of the computer you are trying to reach. It needs to consult a list to look up which IP address Google.com has today.

First your computer will look in it's DNS cache (Domain Name System), as if you've been to the site recently then the PC doesn't need to do any more look ups.

Then, it'll look in the Hosts file, to see if you've written down the IP address of that site yourself.

If your PC has no luck finding the right IP locally, it'll ask the DNS server listed in your network card settings. Usually the setting says "automatic" which means that your PC asks your router to find out, and if the router is set to default settings then the request gets forwarded to your ISP's DNS service.

If the ISP knows the right IP address, it will tell your PC, and your PC will then connect to Google.com. Otherwise, your ISP's DNS servers will go hunting through other more authoritative DNS servers that have bigger lists of who owns which IP address until it finds it.

Because it can take a little time to look up DNS addresses occasionally, there may be performance reasons to type data straight into your hosts file. And in corporate networks it may be necessary to have certain internal servers listed manually. More often for the home user though, it gets used to block access to websites by listing the local PC's internal IP of 127.0.0.1 (localhost). For example, you can download [large hostfiles full of adserver names](http://someonewhocares.org/hosts/), and then whenever your PC tries to connect to those servers to load ads the connection will fail and you see no ads.

In the case of your www.sublimetext.com example, whenever the software tries to access the website it will get directed to the local PC (127.0.0.1). Because it won't get a response from your local PC because you're not running a sublime text update server, the update will fail.